# eWay Recurring - Which extension is the best?

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions, eway

One of our clients would like to use eWay for recurring payments in CiviCRM. We have installed and are our testing the eWay recurring extension by ChrisChinchilla. However, while researching other options we also came across the eWay recurring by Agileware and Omnipay extension. It seems the Agileware and Omnipay extensions are receiving more support and updates as the last update for the eWay recurring extension was 2016. Does anyone have any recommendations which is the best option to use for autorenewals for memberships and if any are better for PCI compliance?

Answer (score 1):

I think the agileware version is now updated to use for [eWAY Rapid API](https://www.eway.com.au/features/api-rapid-api/) with the Responsive Shared Page method. This method does not ask for any CC details on civicrm and navigates user to eway site for the payment.

We did hit some problems using it on drupal webform, but I think it is already handled https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.ewayrecurring/issues/4

Comment: Thanks @jitendra. How you used the Omnipay extension as well?

Comment: Hi @jitendra. I tried all the extensions. I might be missing something but I can't see the token or recurring payment in the eWay admin for the agileware version or the omnipay version. It does show up for the ChrisChinchilla eWay version. Do you know where the autorenewals are stored in eWay admin and how can an admin/user update their card details.